# OpenGL4 objects are unintentionally “linked” together on delete / cleanup

Tags: c++, qt, opengl

I have three test objects created like this. **If I delete obj 3, it works as expected. If I delete obj 2 it deletes 2 and 3. If I delete object 1 it deletes 1 and 2 and attaches one of my vao/vbos to my camera object.**

**I think there might be a problem with the assignment constructor. If I just copy the copy constructor, I can delete the 1st object as I would expect, but it crashes immediately afterwards.**

```
vector<Object> allObj;

//MAINWINDOW
Object *persp;
Object *grid;

persp = new Object(*this);
persp->rename("persp", myEtc->allObj); persp->type->val_s = "cam";
myEtc->allObj.push_back(*persp);
delete persp;

grid = new Object(*this);
grid->rename("grid", myEtc->allObj); grid->type->val_s = "grid";
grid->t->val_3 = glm::vec3(-3.f, 0.f, 0.f);
myEtc->allObj.push_back(*grid);
delete grid;

grid = new Object(*this);
grid->rename("grid", myEtc->allObj); grid->type->val_s = "grid";
myEtc->allObj.push_back(*grid);
delete grid;

grid = new Object(*this);
grid->rename("grid", myEtc->allObj); grid->type->val_s = "grid";
grid->t->val_3 = glm::vec3(-1.f, 0.5f, 0.f);
myEtc->allObj.push_back(*grid);
delete grid;

void MainWindow::deleteItem()
{
    for (vector<Object>::iterator iter = myEtc->allObj.begin(); iter != myEtc->allObj.end();)
    {
        if ((*iter).highlight == myGLHelp->highlight)
        {
            qDebug() << "name = " << (*iter).name->val_s;
            (*iter).delete_();
            iter = myEtc->allObj.erase(iter);
            break;
        }

        else
            ++iter;
    }

    myGL->updateGL();
}

//GLWIDGET - 4.4
void GLWidget::paintGL()
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glEnable(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_SRGB);

    for (int i = 0; i < myWin.myEtc->allObj.size(); ++i)
    {
        if (myWin.myEtc->allObj[i].v->val_b)
        {
            if (myWin.myEtc->allObj[i].loadedVaoVbo == 0)
                myWin.myEtc->allObj[i].loadVaoVbo(); // dont load every frame

            myWin.myEtc->allObj[i].render(ProjectionM * ViewM);
        }
    }
}

//bullet raycast picking in GL viewport sets the color of the highlight - from non(0,0,0) to selected (yellow)

//OBJECT
Object & Object::operator=(const Object &obj) //ASSIGNMENT CONSTRUCTOR
{
    if (this == &obj) // Check for self assignment
      return *this;

    //same as copy constructor

    return *this;
}

Object::Object(const Object &obj) : myWin(obj.myWin) //COPY CONSTRUCTOR
{
    keyable.resize(obj.keyable.size());
    nonkeyable.resize(obj.nonkeyable.size());

    for (int i = 0; i < obj.keyable.size(); ++i)
    {
        keyable[i] = obj.keyable[i]->clone();

        if (keyable[i]->name == obj.keyable[i]->name)
        {
            if (keyable[i]->name == "name")
                name = keyable[i];

            else if (keyable[i]->name == "t")
                t = keyable[i];

            else if (keyable[i]->name == "r")
                r = keyable[i];

            else if (keyable[i]->name == "s")
                s = keyable[i];

            else if (keyable[i]->name == "v")
                v = keyable[i];

            //cam
            else if (keyable[i]->name == "camType")
                camType = keyable[i];

            else if (keyable[i]->name == "fov")
                fov = keyable[i];

            else if (keyable[i]->name == "lookAt")
                lookAt = keyable[i];

            else if (keyable[i]->name == "nearClip")
                nearClip = keyable[i];

            else if (keyable[i]->name == "farClip")
                farClip = keyable[i];
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < obj.nonkeyable.size(); ++i)
    {
        nonkeyable[i] = obj.nonkeyable[i]->clone();

        if (nonkeyable[i]->name == "name")
            name = nonkeyable[i];

        else if (nonkeyable[i]->name == "expand")
            expand = nonkeyable[i];

        else if (nonkeyable[i]->name == "mode")
            mode = nonkeyable[i];

        else if (nonkeyable[i]->name == "parent")
            parent = nonkeyable[i];

        else if (nonkeyable[i]->name == "rotOrder")
            rotOrder = nonkeyable[i];

        else if (nonkeyable[i]->name == "type")
            type = nonkeyable[i];

        else if (nonkeyable[i]->name == "piv_r")
            piv_r = nonkeyable[i];

        else if (nonkeyable[i]->name == "piv_t")
            piv_t = nonkeyable[i];
    }

    loadedVaoVbo = 0;
    gridLines = obj.gridLines;
    highlight = obj.highlight;
    boxCollisionShape = obj.boxCollisionShape;
    r_quat = obj.r_quat;
    experimental = 0;
}


void Object::loadVaoVbo()
{
    glGetError();

    if (type->val_s == "grid")
    {
        gridLineLookup();

        gridVerts.resize(gridLines_ * gridLines_);

        gridVertsH.resize(gridLines_ * gridLines_);
        gridVertsV.resize(gridLines_ * gridLines_);

        for (int i = 0; i < gridLines_; ++i)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < gridLines_; ++j)
            {
                gridVertsH[i + j * gridLines_].x =  (i - gridMinus_) / gridMinus_;
                gridVertsH[i + j * gridLines_].z =  (j - gridMinus_) / gridMinus_;

                gridVertsV[i + j * gridLines_].x =  (j - gridMinus_) / gridMinus_;
                gridVertsV[i + j * gridLines_].z =  (i - gridMinus_) / gridMinus_;
            }
        }

        //HORIZONTAL LINES
        glGenVertexArrays(1, &vao_grid1);
        glBindVertexArray(vao_grid1);

        glGenBuffers(1, &vbo_grid1);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo_grid1);
        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, gridVertsH.size() * sizeof(glm::vec3), &gridVertsH[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);
        glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);

        //VERTICAL LINES
        glGenVertexArrays(1, &vao_grid2);
        glBindVertexArray(vao_grid2);

        glGenBuffers(1, &vbo_grid2);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo_grid2);
        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, gridVertsV.size() * sizeof(glm::vec3), &gridVertsV[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);
        glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    }

    myWin.myGLHelp->handleError(" Could not create a VBO", "gl");
    shaderID = loadShaders("grid.vert.glsl", "grid.frag.glsl");
    loadedVaoVbo = 1;
}

void Object::render(glm::mat4 PV)
{
    scaleM = glm::scale(glm::mat4(), s->val_3);
    rotationM = glm::toMat4(r_quat);

    translationM = glm::translate(glm::mat4(), t->val_3);
    transLocal1M = glm::translate(glm::mat4(), -bbCenter);
    transLocal2M = glm::translate(glm::mat4(), bbCenter);
    localSpaceM = transLocal2M * rotationM * scaleM * transLocal1M;

    ModelM = translationM * localSpaceM;
    MVP = PV * ModelM;

    glUseProgram(shaderID);
    MatrixID = glGetUniformLocation(shaderID, "MVP");
    glUniformMatrix4fv(MatrixID, 1, GL_FALSE, &MVP[0][0]);

    if (mode->val_i == 0)
        glUniformMatrix4fv(MatrixID, 1, GL_FALSE, &(MVP * bbM)[0][0]);

    isSelectedID = glGetUniformLocation(shaderID, "isSelected");
    glUniform4f(isSelectedID, highlight[0], highlight[1], highlight[2], highlight[3]);

    glLineWidth(2);
    glEnable(GL_POLYGON_OFFSET_FILL);
    glPolygonOffset(1, 0);

    // RENDER
    if (type->val_s == "grid")
    {
        glBindVertexArray(vao_grid1);
        for (int i = 0; i < gridLines_; ++i)
            glDrawArrays(GL_LINE_STRIP, gridLines_ * i, gridLines_);

        glBindVertexArray(vao_grid2);
        for (int i = 0; i < gridLines_; ++i)
            glDrawArrays(GL_LINE_STRIP, gridLines_ * i, gridLines_);
    }
}

void Object::delete_()
{
    if (type->val_s == "grid")
    {
        glUseProgram(NULL);
        glDeleteProgram(this->shaderID);
        myWin.myGLHelp->handleError("Couldnt delete shaders", "gl");

        glBindVertexArray(0);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
        glDeleteVertexArrays(1, &vao_grid1);
        glDeleteVertexArrays(1, &vao_grid2);

        glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

        glDeleteBuffers(1, &vbo_grid1);
        glDeleteBuffers(1, &vbo_grid2);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your assignment constructor is wrong! You are supposed to copy the object on assignment. Instead you just return a reference to the first object!

Comment: so whats the difference between that and my copy constructor? Why is it that if i copy/paste my copy constructor into my assignment that i can successfully delete the 1st object, but on the next object i try to delete i crash? Any good resources for this? Thanks.

Comment: This is because rather than making a copy of the objects managed by GL (e.g. shader, VBO, etc.) you just copy the name of the object. Thus you have two or more copies of your object both keeping a reference to the same GL name. When one of those objects is deleted, your destructor destroys the resource that ***both*** objects point to. When you call the destructor for the copy of your object, it tries to destroy something that was already destroyed. You should not need to unnecessarily copy any data, just add a reference counting mechanism to prevent this for copies that can share data.

Comment: My class is rather large - I dont really know how to implement what you suggest although I just looked. Do you have any links to anything similar?

Comment: If you use boost, you can use the `shared_ptr` template, which has reference counting semantics. Allocate your objects on the heap, and then **consistently** use `shared_ptr` to reference them, pass them around, store them in containers, etc. Having OpenGL objects encapsulated in C++ wrappers can easily go wrong, even after you fix the bad copy constructor. There's really no good way to implement copy/assignment properly, particularly if you want to delete the GL objects in the destructor. I normally disable copy/assignment for these kinds of objects.